# Symfony, how to keep the declaration of entities repository after re-import my table

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, console

The structure of the database I am using for my project is constantly changed by another team. So I have to import regularly this structure into Symfony. To do so I use the following command:

```
php app/console doctrine:mapping:import --force EgBundle yml [--filter="Table"] 
php app/console doctrine:generate:entities [Company/EgBundle/Entity/Table]
```

Every time I run those command I loose the declaration of my repositories and I have to had them manually:

```
repositoryClass: Company\EgBundle\Entity\TableRepository
```

Is there any way to keep this declaration?

Comment: Just for my information, can't the team do the opposite thing?  
Or rather write them with "annotation" or somehing like this and generate the "inverse" command (php app/console doctrine:schema:update)

Comment: The change are done directly on the database. So I have to import all the time the new structure.

Comment: Yes, is clear to me... My question is: can't those changes be made directly into the code and AFTER that, reproduced onto db?

Comment: The other team has no skill in programming and they must not touch to the frontend side.

Comment: I understand but I think that isn't a way to do this

Comment: I would like to do it otherwise to, but the backend is almost done by database expert in finance, with stored procedure and so on. I must follow their requirement...

Answer (score 2):

There is no way for Doctrine to know what the repository class shall be when importing a mapping from database. The information can't be obtained from the database schema.

A possible solution for your use-case would be extending\overriding the `doctrine:mapping:import` command to add a Repository to the mapping information automatically using a naming convention.

Comment: +1 i was going to write pretty much the same but you were faster :)

Comment: Thanks, I will give a try to your proposition and give you a feedback concerning my solution.